# Yii 2 Консоль

Tags: php, yii, linux

Здравствуйте, проблема с консолью в yii 2

Сделал следующиму по [мануалу](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-console.html#usage)

**Приложение**: Basic

```
//config/console.php     
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
```

Контроллер [console/controllers/StoreController.php](https://codeo.me/5le)

при вводе в терминал: php yii store/test я получаю ошибку:

```
Error: Неизвестная команда "store/test".
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to append to log file: /path/to/www/yii2/runtime/logs/app.log' in /path/to/www/yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/FileTarget.php:93
```

в чем может быть проблема?

---

дал права папке runtime 777  теперь ошибка выглядит вот так:

user@user:~/www/yii2$ php yii store/test
Error: Неизвестная команда "store/test".

А логи в runtime пишут:

Next exception 'yii\console\Exception' with message 'Неизвестная команда "store/test".' in /home/dogmar/www/yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php:162

Comment: `/path/to/www/yii2/runtime/logs/app.log` скорее всего заблокирован для записи, либо папки runtime не существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. /path/to/www/yii2/runtime/logs/app.log - не доступен для записи (видимо он создался юзером под которым запущен web server, как правило www-data, нужно дать права на запись и другим юзерам)
2. php yii store/test - если не ошибаюсь controllerNamespace убрали из конфига, но из логов будет уже виднее и попробуйте просто запустить ./yii там будет список доступных контроллеров

Answer (score 0):

```
//config/console.php     
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
```

укажите:

```
'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
```